# How to know if batchNode has been drawn to the new position by Cocos2d-x/Cocos2d engine

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I have a batchNode and every tick I am scrolling it down , e.g. batchNode->setPositionY(--y); , so all its children are moving down. Now I wan't to restrict the player from using some powers provided in game till batchNode is scrolled down.That is if player uses a power then I will check if bacthNode is scrolled ? if yes then I will take action if not then I will ignore the power used by player

How I can come to know that engine has finished rendering batchNode to the new position . We cannot use getPosition to know if it has been drawn there, as position will be updated immediately but rendering will take a little time, and I wan't to allow player to wait till this little time to use any power.
Please note that I don't wan't to disable touches on those sprites representing powers in my game.
Please share your thoughts.

Comment: you can use callback function..whenever action completed it set some boolean...

Comment: You can simply check the position because if you move the node every tick (frame) at 60 frames per second the time between two frames is 16.666 milliseconds. Too short a time span for the player to really notice or take advantage of.

Comment: @VivekBansal I also thought that can be done , but AFAIK that can be done only in custom actions, where we tell the sequence. @ Steffen but is there any way to know if rendering is finished ?